# Chat en línea php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

tengo un sistema ya hecho. Cabe mencionar que dicho sistema es un proyecto escolar pero me estoy esmerando en hacerlo lo mejor profesional posible.

En este sistema se atienden a usuarios y a "empresas". Me gustaría hacer/implementar un chat en línea para que los usuarios mantengan comunicación con las "empresas" que contacten.

No me imagino otro chat más que al estilo de facebook, pues me agrada que el chat se despliega en la parte lateral y tiene una barra de desplazamiento y un pequeño buscador para hacer la busca de los usuarios.

De primera instancia se que tendría que utilizar Ajax, php, y css para poder maquetar dicho chat. Ahora, dicho lo anterior, lo que me imagino, es un jQuery haciendo peticiones cada segundo para actualizar la ventana del chat, esto multiplicado por cada usuario y empresa podría volverse una locura.

Cabe mencionar que aún no tengo código de esto que deseo hacer, pero la verdad es que nisiquiera se por donde empezar.

Lo que necesito saber si existe alguna librería para hacer esto y que consuma la menor cantidad de recursos posibles.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que has preguntado aquí debes preguntárselo a Google. Tu pregunta tal y como está no se adapta al formato del sitio. Como comentario, no tienes por qué estar enviando peticiones al servidor de forma indiscriminada. Solamente tienes que *escuchar*  el input o textarea donde se escriben los mensajes y cuando haya cambios actualizas ambas interfaces, la del emisor y la del receptor. Es sólo una idea, puede haber otras formas de hacerlo. Te toca pues investigar.

Comment: Claro, cohincido contigo, google es lo mejor, solo que estamos de acuerdo que cuando no se sabe que buscar es más complicado. Acá no espero que me resuelvan la existencia, si no que me digan que herramientas son las mejores para este tipo (basados en la experiencia) y listo, con eso yo googleo. También entiendo lo de la estructura de pregunta, solo que, en base a la necesidad me vi obligado a hacerlo por si alguna alma caritativa me puede orientar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Investiga un poco de "sockets PHP" esa es la solución sin duda, sería de locos poner aquí ese código.

Comment: No es tan complicado escribir algo como *php mysql chat room tutorial*  en Google, y encontrarás enlaces [como este](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/), o como [este otro](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html) ... y así, muchísimos enlaces. Como ya sabrás, los mejores tutoriales están escritos en inglés. Puede que en castellano encuentres algo que valga la pena, pero no siempre es así.

Comment: actualmente tengo mi chat montado en php y node js usando sockets, es lo mas eficiente que te puedo recomendar

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, si usas jquery cada 1 segundo, la carga sobre el servidor va a ser bastante, no te lo recomiendo. lo mejor es investigar un poco otras tecnologias mas acordes al tema chat, como:

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

o como en este tutorial, utilizando node:

https://www.uno-de-piera.com/chat-con-node-js-express-y-socketio/